# Nodemailer Include Table Iterating Through An Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to use nodemailer to send an email with an HTML table. The table needs to iterate through an array. Currently the way it's working is it sends a separate email for each iteration, rather than a single email with the table. I've tried moving the for loop into transporter.sendMail(), however, that just keeps returning syntax errors.

The fteData array is defined above and working properly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

### JS code

```
for(var s = 0; s < fteData.length; s++) {
    var rows = fteData[s];
    let login = rows.login;
    let fte = rows.fte;
    let start = rows.start;
    let end = rows.end;
    let sun = rows.sun;
    let mon = rows.mon;
    let tue = rows.tue;
    let wed = rows.wed;
    let thu = rows.thu;
    let fri = rows.fri;
    let sat = rows.sat;
    let lunch_start = rows.lunch_start;
    let lunch_end = rows.lunch_end;
    let lunch2_start = rows.lunch2_start;
    let lunch2_end = rows.lunch2_end;
    let updated_by = rows.updated_by;
    let timestamp = rows.timestamp;


    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport()) ;  
      transporter.sendMail({
      'from': 'from@email.com',
      'to': 'to@email.com',
      'subject': 'Test',
      'html':
        '<table style="border: 1px solid #333;">' +
          '<thead>' +
            '<th> login </th>' +
            '<th> fte </th>' +
            '<th> start </th>' +
            '<th> end </th> ' + 
            '<th> sun </th> ' + 
            '<th> mon </th> ' + 
            '<th> tue </th> ' + 
            '<th> wed </th> ' + 
            '<th> thu </th> ' + 
            '<th> fri </th> ' + 
            '<th> sat </th> ' + 
            '<th> lunch_start </th> ' + 
            '<th> lunch_end </th> ' + 
            '<th> lunch2_start </th> ' + 
            '<th> lunch2_end </th> ' + 
            '<th> updated_by </th> ' + 
            '<th> timestamp </th> ' + 
          '</thead>' +
          '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + login + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + fte + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + start + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + end + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + sun + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + mon + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + tue + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + wed + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + thu + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + fri + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + sat + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + lunch_start + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + lunch_end + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + lunch2_start + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + lunch2_end + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + updated_by + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + timestamp + '</td>' +
          '</tr>' +
        '</table>'

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build up a string with the data:

```
let message = (
  '<table style="border: 1px solid #333;">' +
  '<thead>' +
  '<th> login </th>' +
  '<th> fte </th>'  +
  /*...*/
  '</thead>'
); 

for(const { login, fte, start /*...*/ } of fteData) {
   message += (
     '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + login + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + fte + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + start + '</td>' +
      /*...*/
    '</tr>'
   );
}

message +=  '</table>';
```

Then you can easily send the whole message:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport()) ;  

transporter.sendMail({
  'from': 'from@email.com',
  'to': 'to@email.com',
  'subject': 'Test',
  'html': message
});
```

Comment: YES! That did it and that completely makes sense. I tried to do something similar but it failed miserably haha. Thank you for the excellent solution!